# Router control panel ip serves localhost

Tags: windows-10, router

I want to open my router control panel which is located at 192.168.178.1 but my pc serves me the localhost page if i am hosting one and if i don't just refuses to connect.

I can access this page normally on all my other devices.
I already looked at the hosts file in windows but it has no entries.

[image: screenshot not working pc]

[image: screenshot working laptop]

Comment: What address are you actually typing? Try the full correct URL. If your working machine is on Ethernet & the non-working is on WiFi, that could in itself be the reason. Stops fly-by attacks by not allowing admin over wifi.

Comment: @Tetsujin i am typing 192.168.178.1 but it just redirects to those 2. Both machines are on wifi on the same band.

Answer (score 0):

Someone on my discord found the answer, it had to do with a virtual network adapter from vmware. Disabling the adapter fixed the issue.